# Save out plot and plot legend

Tags: eps-format

I am attempting to save out a plot to .eps file, but cannot get the legend to come with it. Copying and pasting the image, saving as a JPEG and converting to .eps loses too much resolution for it too look good. Is there any way that I can save out a plot with its legend directly to .eps from Mathematica?

Comment: I tried `Export["try.eps", Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotLegends -> {"sin", "cos"}]]` and I got [this from the eps](https://imgur.com/GY5uLe7), which contains the legends. You will want to shared an example with complete code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @MarcoB that worked, if you want to write that as an answer I will accept it! Thanks!

Comment: done! Glad to hear that it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Export[
  "try.eps", 
  Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotLegends -> {"sin", "cos"}]
]
```

works as intended once exported to EPS.